# css3 media queries

Tags: css3, media-queries

Прочитал [здесь](http://myresolutionis.ru/page/smapage.php), что ширина айфона 5 - 640 пикселей.
Но на `media screen and (width: 640px)` он не реагирует (на компе со сжиманием окошка работает). Почему реальная ширина не совпадает с той, которую видит браузер?

Comment: скорее всего ответ найдете здесь
http://frontender.com.ua/mobile-web/wtf-viewport/
и странно почему вы не используете min-width and max-width, просто не сталкивался еще со случаями когда нужно было точное значение для медиа запроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> @media screen and (width: 640px)
> ```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
```

Ну и не забыть про

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Вопрос все таки немного другой: почему количество пикселей телефона, на которое реагирует media query отличается от реального?

Comment: вам уже дали ответ 2 раза, viewport коварен)  frontender.com.ua/mobile-web/wtf-viewport если не поленитесь прочитать - то все поймете

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> после такой строки, по идее, должно реагировать на width: 640px (ровно 640), но этого не происходит

Comment: Да может они вообще на такой вариант правила забили, ибо никто не использует его? Ну либо перебирай ширину.

Comment: @Qwertiy А если этого не использовать, то сколько пикселей в ширину максимум стоит считать телефоном?

Comment: @Юрий, а зачем считать телефоном? Просто берёшь свой сайт и смотришь, при какой ширине получается фигня. Ну или можно на js проверять на тачскрин.

Comment: http://mobiledetect.net/ - ставите как плагин на сайт и дальше разбор полетов, какие вьюхи показывать, стили подключать и тд

Comment: ну и скорее всего мобильные телефоны данного фактора ведут себя как 320px устройства

Comment: @sivik_xes, парсеры user-agent'а - зло.

Comment: @Qwertiy можешь объяснить подробнее...